# Thread 1: Signal SIGABRT (Could not cast value of type to 'SignInViewController' to 'AWSCognitoIdentityPasswordAuthentication')

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

So far when after completing the username and password fields in my `SignInViewController`.

This is what the code looks like:

**Code from SignInViewControllerExtension class**

```
func startPasswordAuthentication() -> AWSCognitoIdentityPasswordAuthentication {
        return self as! AWSCognitoIdentityPasswordAuthentication
}
```

My `SignInViewControllerExtensions` throws a **Thread 1: Signal SIGABRT** error with the following message in the debug area:

> Could not cast value of type 'Elixr.SignInViewController' (0x1001460a8) to 'AWSCognitoIdentityPasswordAuthentication' (0x100134468).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably trying to assign `Elixr.SignInViewController` as `AWSCognitoIdentityPasswordAuthentication` somewhere. But I can't say more without looking at the actual code.

But I'm guessing it's going to look something like this...

```
let someVc = SignInViewController(args_here) as! AWSCognitoIdentityPasswordAuthentication
```

The `as!` above is trying to **force cast** something that is not `AWSCognito...` so the code is going to crash.

Comment: @TimmyT what's `self` here? I'm guessing it's not `AWSCognitoIdentityPasswordAuthentication`

Comment: I have added all the code. 'Self' refers to the `SignInViewController`

Comment: @TimmyT well there you have it. You are assigning  something that is not a `AWSCognitoIdentityPasswordAuthentication` as it forcefully...